# Excel VBA that looks at a form field for text and line breaks and then text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with legacy code here and I'm not sure how much I could or should change, but I have code that looks for something like "SIC CODE 4000"
However the data html database I pull it from (we use a copy and paste) has updated their code to have:

"SiC CODE

4000"

Currently the code is:

```
Const strSic = "SIC Code "
```

However I now need it to add line breaks.

I tried modifying the code to say:

```
Const strSic = "SIC Code" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
```

But I get a compile error saying "Constant expression required"

I tried using "SIC Code \n\n\n" but maybe I'm not thinking the right character for line break.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it need to be a Const? Maybe just use it as a variable?

Answer (score 2):

The code for a new line is `vbNewLine`:

```
Const strSic = "SIC Code" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```

**Update:**

To be a bit more detailed see the [VBA constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278800.aspx):

- `vbNewLine = Chr(13)+Chr(10)` on Windows and `Chr(13)` on Mac
- `vbCr = Chr(13)`
- `vbLf = Chr(10)`

So if you only need `Chr(10)` you should use `vbLf` (like Excel Hero's answer).

Comment: vbNewLine is NOT the correct constant if OP needs  only ASCII 10.

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't get an error, but its still not finding the text though. I looked at the text in notepad and it seems that it has "line break" "line break" "space" "line break" "line break" So I tried: <code>Const strSic = "SIC Code" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine</code> but it still doesn't work. I may have to look elsewhere to see what the code is doing.

Comment: How are you defining "line break"? Which ascii codes?

Comment: Here is my code now: `Const strSic = "SIC Code" & vbLf & vbLf & " " & vbLf & vbLf ` Still not working. I don't know if its the space or it doesn't like the line breaks. `SIC Code

 

3663 `

Comment: You could try to print the character codes of those 'new lines' in your file using [`Asc` or `AscW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: It looks like that isn't the code to start and stop the search of text. I found some other code that seems to determine the stop and start `.txtSicCode = ParseDnbi(.txtEmailHeader, strSic, Chr(10))` Basically strSic determines the start and Chr(10) (the line break) determines its stop. However, I'm not sure what a good stop now is because we need it to ignore the first 4 line breaks and settle on the 5th as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Const strSic = "SIC Code" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf
```

Comment: @JamesDouglas If you cannot get this going, please send me a sample workbook with the data and the VBA you are trying. I'll sort it for you. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Ah sorry. Its contains work related stuff so cannot send it out. Thanks for trying to help though. Currently the person who normally handles this is out so I will have to wait for them to come in. I think I have it narrowed down to the fact its looking for a chr(10) to where it stops looking at the text. The problem is that I need it to ignore the first 4 line breaks and then stop at the 5th. Not sure how one would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes vbNewLine is the correct code : )

Comment: vbNewLine is NOT the correct constant if OP needs  only ASCII 10.